# Huffman dictionary does not have the codes for all the input signals

Tags: matlab, huffman-code

I seem to be having a problem passing the string and dictionary through the `huffmanenco` function. I've tried almost everything, but the I keep getting the error that the Huffman dictionary does not have all the input codes. Yet I'm positive it does.

```
%% HUFFMAN TEST
clear all; close all; clc;


sig = ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'; 'g'; 'h'; 'i'; 'j';...
            'k'; 'l'; 'm'; 'n'; 'o'; 'p'; 'q'; 'r'; 's'; 't';...
            'u'; 'v'; 'w'; 'x'; 'y'; 'z'; ':'; ' '; ','; '.'];



% Get probability
char_count = zeros(30,1);

for i = 1:30
    for c = sig(i)
        char_count(i,1) = length(find(sig == c));
    end
end

sym_prob = char_count / sum(char_count);


% Huffman Dictionary
% symbols = cellstr(symbols); % Still doesn't work in huffmandict, so try manually typing out again with curly braces
sig = {'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'; 'g'; 'h'; 'i'; 'j';...
            'k'; 'l'; 'm'; 'n'; 'o'; 'p'; 'q'; 'r'; 's'; 't';...
            'u'; 'v'; 'w'; 'x'; 'y'; 'z'; ':'; ' '; ','; '.'};

[dict, aveLength] = huffmandict(sig, sym_prob);


% Process signal
str = 'A technique is developed to construct a representation of planar objects undergoing a general affine transformation. The representation can be used to describe planar or nearly planar objects in a three-dimensional space, observed by a camera under arbitrary orientations.';
str_int = bin2dec(dec2bin(str));

sig = cell(size(str));
for i = 1:length(str)
    sig{i} = char(str_int(i));
end


% Encode & Decode
sig_enco = huffmanenco(sig, dict);
dsig = huffmandeco(sig_enco, dict);
```

Answer (score 2):

You *don't* have all the characters present in your dictionary. You can easily check this using [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) on your dictionary symbols and your input signal. I get the following list of characters which are not present in your dictionary.

```
dictionary_symbols = { ...
        'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'; 'g'; 'h'; 'i'; 'j';...
        'k'; 'l'; 'm'; 'n'; 'o'; 'p'; 'q'; 'r'; 's'; 't';...
        'u'; 'v'; 'w'; 'x'; 'y'; 'z'; ':'; ' '; ','; '.'};

[isListed, ind] = ismember(sig, dictionary_symbols);

sig(~isListed)

    'A'  'T'  '-'
```

It may be easier (and possibly more robust) to use an ASCII code range to generate your dictionary so you can ensure that you capture all the *basic* characters you intend to catch.

```
dictionary_symbols = num2cell(char(' ':'~')).';
probabilities = ones(size(dictionary_symbols)) ./ numel(dictionary_symbols);
```

**Addendum**

I'm not completely sure what you're doing with this code chunk

```
% Process signal
str_int = bin2dec(dec2bin(str));

sig = cell(size(str));
for i = 1:length(str)
    sig{i} = char(str_int(i));
end
```

If you want the numeric representation of your string, you can always cast it using the desired datatype.

```
uint8(str);
double(str);
```

Then if you want to split a string up so that it's a cell array where each element is a separate character, you can use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html).

```
cellArray = num2cell(str);
```